# merge some columns from some tables into one new table

Tags: mysql

I need to create new table and, after that, copy some columns of some table into the new table. Three columns from the first table. Five columns from the second table. Three columns from the third table. Three columns from the fourth table.

The columns from table one: `eid(primary key),first name,last name,status`.
The columns from table two: `mid(primary key), sender, subject,body,folder`.
The columns from table three: `rid(primary key) , mid ,rvalue`.
The columns from table four: `rfid(primary key), mid, reference`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Columns are not that important. What *rows* would You insert into the new table?

Comment: each column hava 149 rows..i want to copy all of them raws into new table.

Comment: Then simply use `INSERT INTO newtable(...) SELECT whatever from the old tables`. How do You recognize corresponding rows in the "old" tables?

Comment: i have foreign key and primary key..but i do not know what is the exact syntax of the code for this work.

Comment: "i have foreign key and primary key..but i do not know what...". Probably you must facilitate your work with some mysql-gui like MySqlFront or FlySpeed Sql Query. They have a useful query builders that can cross your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tables are related  between them you could use directly a create table as select  ..

```
    create table your_table as 
    select 
        a.col1
        , a.col2
        , a.col3
        , b.col1
        , b.col2
        , b.col3
        , b.col5
        , c.col1
        , c.col2
        , c.col3
        , d.col1
        , d.col2
        , d.col3
    from table1 a
    inner join table2 b on a.key1 = b.key1
    inner join table3 c on a.key1 = c.key1
    inner join table4 d on a.key1 = d.key1
```

this create the resulting table direcly from select

otherwise you can use an insert select

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO new_table (field_1,field_2...field_n)
SELECT first_table.column_1
    ,first_table.column_2
    ,first_table.column_3
    ,second_table.column_1
    ,second_table.column_2
    ,second_table.column_3
    ,second_table.column_4
    ,second_table.column_5
    ,third_table.column_1
    ,third_table.column_2
    ,third_table.column_3
    ,fourth_table.column_1
    ,fourth_table.column_2
    ,fourth_table.column_3
FROM first_table
INNER JOIN second_table ON first_table.field_to_join = second_table.field_to_join
INNER JOIN third_table ON second_table.field_to_join = third_table.field_to_join
INNER JOIN fourth_table ON third_table.field_to_join = fourth_table.field_to_join
```

Clearly, you have to tune your query, your joins/type of joins and fields according to your needs.

In `(field_1,field_2...field_n)` you have to indicate fields where the output of the select query will go.